# Android eclipse ERROR: Unknown option '--auto-add-overlay'

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-construction, sdk

I had an abnormal shutdown of my mac and when it came back up, Eclipse would no longer compile my project correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gone through this [link1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8498) and [link2](http://bramp.net/blog/android-sdk-r6-aapt-library-bug)

Comment: OK - that lead me to my root cause.  The solution was to download the Android SDK and re-configure my Eclipse Android projects to use the new SDK components.  The root cause, as it turns out, was a poor installation originally and then the automatic updates failed. When I first started building-out my MacBook, I did part under a different local account and then completed it under the account I wanted to use regularly.  This caused the update to fail with "Permissions denied."  This became apparent during the upgrade attempt to the original account's folder from the preferred account's folder.